# Getting Error Cannot find module 'gulp-util' when trying to run gulp?

Tags: gulp

```
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-util'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/gulp/bin/gulp.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

this is an idiotic problem but I can't fix it. When I run gulp watch, it's trying to run some random gulpfile in /usr/lib/nodejs/gulp/bin/gulp.js which isn't what I want or created. I can't figure out how to make it run the gulpfile in the actual directory that I'm in.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling gulp seemed to fix it.